# How to get Opportunity Stage History SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, opportunity, opportunity-history

What is the best way to get Opportunity Stage Change History using SOQL?

Basically, what I need is the same list as in Opportunity page in Salesforce, where list of stages and dates of modifications are listed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the OpportunityFieldHistory Object for this.

```
    List<OpportunityFieldHistory> history = [Select Id, CreatedById, CreatedDate,
 Field, NewValue, OldValue from OpportunityFieldHistory Where Field = 'StageName'];
```

Comment: Could you point me to the documentation about enabling field history(the collection is empty now)? Cannot find it with google.

Comment: Sure.  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history_for_standard_objects.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [OpportunityHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunityhistory.htm) object

```
SELECT StageName, Probability, Amount FROM OpportunityHistory where OpportunityId = {YourOppId}
```

if you are doing it in Apex, you can use relationship query like this

```
List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT id,
        (SELECT StageName,Probability,Amount FROM OpportunityHistories) 
        FROM Opportunity];

List<OpportunityHistory> histories = opp.OpportunityHistories
```

you can also use [OpportunityFieldHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunityfieldhistory.htm) which will give you the history of all the fields on the opportunity for which field tracking is enabled.